# Is it possible to send a message to the Bot Framework as if it were from the user?

Tags: javascript, c#, botframework

I'm using Direct Line 3.0 and the Microsoft Bot Framework and require the webpage to send some form fields to the bot as if the user sent them. For example when the user presses Submit, the fields email, phone etc are sent to the bot as if the user sent them like this: email, phone, etc. 
This is because the bot redirects the user depending on what the values are. The bot is in C# and is hosted on Azure. The logic for submitting the information should be in JavaScript.

Bot is initiated like this:

```
<div id="chat" style="background-color:white;   
   width:250px;height:600px;"><div id="bot" />
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-
webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script></div></div>
```

and through a DirectLine script:

```
<script>
    const botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
        secret: 'secret',
    });

    BotChat.App({
        user: { id: 'You' },
        bot: { id: 'myId' },
        resize: 'detect',
        botConnection: botConnection
    }, document.getElementById("bot"));

</script>
```

All I need is to send one string as if the user sent it. I cannot do this with HTML manipulation it seems.

Thanks for anyone pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending a message to the bot "like the user would do" is possible using the "Backchannel" functionnality of the webchat.

There is a good sample of use in the Readme file on Github webchat's page: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#the-backchannel.

You have to use your `botConnection` previously created to send an activity like the following:

```
botConnection.postActivity({
    from: { id: 'me' },
    name: 'buttonClicked',
    type: 'event',
    value: ''
});
```

Then catch this on your bot code, but checking the Activity type which will be `Event` in this case.

You can have a look on how they throw this postActivity from a button click in the sample provided: samples here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/backchannel/index.html

Or in this other [sample](https://github.com/nrobert/Bot-Language-Demo/tree/master/Bot.Language.Demo) that I made (available on Github, both client web page and bot code): the bot's controller looks like the following:

```
[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        // Process each activity
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
        }
        // Webchat: getting an "event" activity for our js code
        else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event && activity.ChannelId == "webchat")
        {
            var receivedEvent = activity.AsEventActivity();

            if ("localeSelectionEvent".Equals(receivedEvent.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                await EchoLocaleAsync(activity, activity.Locale);
            }
        }
        // Sample for Skype: locale is provided in ContactRelationUpdate event
        else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate && activity.ChannelId == "skype")
        {
            await EchoLocaleAsync(activity, activity.Entities[0].Properties["locale"].ToString());
        }

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }

    private async Task EchoLocaleAsync(Activity activity, string inputLocale)
    {
        Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"User locale is {inputLocale}, you should use this language for further treatment");
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(reply);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see... so for the bot code, does something like this look right? : public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            if(activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event)
            {
                activity.value = what I set in the post?
            }
? 
Am I right in assuming the postActivity method runs the Post method?

Comment: Yes you are right. In the bot it's still arriving in your Post method in MessagesController, it's like a message. You can event send an activity of type "message" if you want

Comment: I made a sample a few weeks ago about the backchannel, I'm adding it to the answer

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for the example. I did something similar while trying to figure this out and the end result after trying your code is the same, the bot has sent the event values back and the code has not processed the data as if the user had sent it, if that makes sense. When the button is pressed, the data is passing fine to the bot, however it isn't processing it as I thought it might. Is there anymore information I can provide for you to assist me more? Many thanks.

Comment: Without more code details about your form, your postActivity implementation and your bot code that should handle these information, I can't help you more on that

Comment: To be honest you've helped me get the data to the Bot which has helped a lot so thank you for that, I will try my best to resolve this and will comment here if I do.

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer and have managed to get this to work. I added a public string to the rootdialog and in the controller I checked if the message started with a particular set of characters, this was how I checked if the message was the automated data sender. This then set the string which had its values read in by the rootdialog. Thanks again.