# Can I pass information from the webpage to Bot Framework Web Chat

Tags: botframework

Is there any way to pass information into the bot from the webpage.  I have a Bot Framework bot using Web Chat embedded in an iframe on an aspx page. Ultimately I would like to dynamically set the filtering tag used by QnA Maker in the bot based on the business line that a user is in.  Rather than make them tell the bot which business line they represent, I would like to be able to pass the information to the bot automatically.

Here is the iframe just for reference:

```
<iframe src="https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/bdous-prod-newhire-bcr?s={my secret}" id="webchat"></iframe>
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Dylan

Comment: Use the backchannel of Webchat. See topics https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008420/is-it-possible-to-send-a-message-to-the-bot-framework-as-if-it-were-from-the-use, and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49532572/how-do-i-send-a-value-from-a-microsoft-bot-to-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can pass username and userid in the iframe and then perform a specific process against this user.

```
<iframe src="https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/YOUR_BOT_ID?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE&username=USERNAME&userid=USER_ID"></iframe>
```

Comment: If we passed the username this way, how would we access it via the bot? In this case, we're using the C# Bot Builder SDK.

Answer (score 0):

As Nicolas R indicated, you should use the backchannel to perform your ask.

There are two samples you should look at (they actually need to be used together to have the full example running). They are this [backChannelBot](https://github.com/ryanvolum/backChannelBot) and the [BotFramework-WebChat/samples/backchannel](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/backchannel) sample.

From the first sample, the important code you need to examine can be found in the [`app.js`](https://github.com/ryanvolum/backChannelBot/blob/master/app.js) file:

```
//Bot listening for inbound backchannel events - in this case it only listens for events named "buttonClicked"
bot.on("event", function (event) {
  var msg = new builder.Message().address(event.address);
  msg.textLocale("en-us");
  if (event.name === "buttonClicked") {
    msg.text("I see that you just pushed that button");
  }
  bot.send(msg);
})

//Basic root dialog which takes an inputted color and sends a changeBackground event. No NLP, regex, validation here - just grabs input and sends it back as an event. 
bot.dialog('/', [
  function (session) {
    var reply = createEvent("changeBackground", session.message.text, session.message.address);
    session.endDialog(reply);
  }
]);

//Creates a backchannel event
const createEvent = (eventName, value, address) => {
  var msg = new builder.Message().address(address);
  msg.data.type = "event";
  msg.data.name = eventName;
  msg.data.value = value;
  return msg;
}
```

And the relevant portion of code from the WebChat sample is this [section](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/backchannel/index.html#L101L125):

```
  botConnection.activity$
    .filter(function (activity) {
      return activity.type === 'event' && activity.name === 'changeBackgroundColor';
    })
    .subscribe(function (activity) {
      console.log('"changeBackground" received with value: ' + activity.value);
      changeBackgroundColor(activity.value);
    });

  function changeBackgroundColor(newColor) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('wc-message-groups')[0].style.backgroundColor = newColor;
  }

  function postButtonMessage(color) {
    botConnection
      .postActivity({
        from: { id: 'me' },
        name: 'changeBackgroundColor',
        type: 'event',
        value: color
      })
      .subscribe(function (id) {
        console.log('"changeBackgroundColor" sent');
      });
  }
```